# Twilio WhatsApp messages are in 'queued' status

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

Okay so I got approval from WhatsApp and Twilio (after Facebook Business verification) to use the WhatsApp API for sending out appointment reminders to my clients. I configured the message templates and they got approved too. Check the image below:

[image: Twilio approval]

I have written a code in Python where I pick my data from a PostgreSQL server hosted on cloud (using psycopg2) and then it sends out messages to the phone numbers fetched using a query. Here is the code:

```
from twilio.rest import Client
import psycopg2
import time

account_sid = 'AC54xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
auth_token = 'f1384yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy'

connection_string = ""

conn = psycopg2.connect(user = "xxxx",
                    password = "yyyyyy",
                    host = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz.zzzzzzzzzzzz",
                    port = "ABCD",
                    database = "some_db")

cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""query to pick data""")

rows = cur.fetchall()

client_phone_list = []
phone_list_not_received = []
session_date_list = []
session_time_list = []
client_first_name_list = []

for row in rows:
    session_date_list.append(row[0])
    session_time_list.append(row[1])
    client_first_name_list.append(row[2])
    client_phone_list.append(row[3])

cur.close()
conn.close()

client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

message_reminder_template = """Hello {},

This is a reminder about your session today at {}. Please be on time to utilize the full length of 
the session and avoid distress :)

We look forward to taking care of you!"""

for i in range(len(client_phone_list)):
    first_name = client_first_name_list[i]
    appointment_time = session_time_list[i]
    message_body = message_reminder_template.format(first_name, appointment_time)
    print(message_body)

message = client.messages.create(body = str(message_body),
                                 from_ = 'whatsapp:+1(mytwilionumber)',
                                 to = 'whatsapp:+91'+client_phone_list[i])
time.sleep(10)
text_status = message.status
print(text_status)
```

Whenever I run this code the message status returned is always 'queued'. I have checked that I am not using the 'Test Credentials' but the 'Live Credentials'.

I have also checked the error_code and error_message which returns as NULL. So there is no error but the messages are not getting sent. How can I change that?

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Also note that the message body used in the code above is **approved** as a template from WhatsApp.

Comment: Have you looked at the Twilio Debugger in console, to see if there are any events logged there, https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/troubleshooting/debugging-your-application? Also, can you sent an individual message (with different approved templates), to see what the result is, by following the code snippets here, https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/whatsapp/quickstart. If neither sheds any light, opening a ticket at help@twilio.com with the details of you original post and the results above would be the next step.

Comment: I went into the Twilio debugger but there was no event there. But when I went to the SMS logs i found this : [link](https://imgur.com/a/QvmUn3u). Error 63016 - please use a template. But I reviewed my approved template and it matches with the message exactly how it is supposed to. The approved template: [link](https://imgur.com/DmaNHYT)

Comment: In that case, I suggest emailing help@twilio.com (or opening a ticket from within your Twilio Console), so they can dig into the issue. If you have an exact template match, it shouldn't reject the message.

Comment: I have contacted Twilio support by raising a ticket. Hope to get a solution soon. Will post the solution as soon as I have one incase someone is facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

At the point that you make the API request to send the message the status will be returned to code as "queued". That's this point in your code here:

```py
message = client.messages.create(body = str(message_body),
                                 from_ = 'whatsapp:+1(mytwilionumber)',
                                 to = 'whatsapp:+91'+client_phone_list[i])
```

What you do next will not work though:

```py
time.sleep(10)
text_status = message.status
print(text_status)
```

Waiting 10 seconds and then reading the status from the message object that was returned when you created the message will still return "queued".

If you want to fetch the message status after 10 seconds to see if it has been sent then you will need to make a second call to the [messages API](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api/message-resource), like so:

```py
time.sleep(10)
latest_message = client.messages(message.sid).fetch()
print(latest_message.status)
```

For a more efficient method of keeping track of the status of your messages, check out this [tutorial on receiving webhooks for message status updates](https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/tutorials/how-to-confirm-delivery-python).

Let me know if that helped at all.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the information. I will make the necessary changes to fetch the status. Although it still does not answer my question. The messages are not getting sent anyway (status of the message is secondary). When I went into the SMS logs it said message failed due to Error 63016 - please use a template. But I am using a template already approved by Twilio. Refer to these images: [link](https://imgur.com/a/QvmUn3u) [link](https://imgur.com/DmaNHYT)

Comment: Your question was why the message was in ‘queued’ status, which is what I tried to answer. I see you’ve contacted support now, they are best placed to check why your templates aren’t working.

Comment: I am marking it as an answer because you are right. I would have stumbled upon it later. Thank you. But this is the first time I'm using Twilio for sending WhatsApp messages and its very complicated (everything from Facebook Business Verification to approval by WhatsApp and WhatsApp Business Account) and very time-consuming. And still after investing so much time I am unable to send a single message even after my message matches the template exactly as it is supposed to.

Comment: I understand, the hoops that you need to jump through to get to this stage are frustrating. I'm sorry you've made it this far and found your template doesn't work as expected. I just had a look at those images, and it looks to me like there may be a space in `a void` in the template, but not your message. Could that be the problem?

Comment: You're just seeing the space because the window is minimized. There is no space in the actual template. Just checked. Also got no reply from Twilio support yet. It's already been a day!

Comment: Fair enough, I just didn't imagine that a word would break like that! If you want to send me your ticket number to philnash@twilio.com, I can try to chase up what's going on.

Comment: Thank you Phil. I really appreciate the help. Ticket number: # 3986680

Comment: As far as I can see, you got a response on that ticket on Sunday that you need to respond to. I'll add this question as notes on the ticket too, and add myself to cc to keep up with it.

Comment: Yes I already replied to the response. Thank you for all the help Phil.